# Mac graphical emacs printing $(D when I press delete

Tags: emacs

When I press the delete (not backspace) key in the GUI version of emacs, it prints $(D to the file (all 3 separate characters plus a space at the end).

The question is how can I fix this so that pressing delete performs a forward delete?

This only happens in my D Language Mode, so in an effort to debug this, I eliminated as much of the `d-mode.el` file as I could while still having the problem/being able to load the file at all... the result looks like this:

```
    (require 'cc-mode)
    (define-derived-mode d-mode nil "" "" nil)
```

I load this file with the following lines in my `.emacs` file:

```
    (autoload 'd-mode "~/.emacs.d/vendor/d-mode" "Major mode for editing D code." t)
    (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.d[i]?\\'" . d-mode))
```

I do not experience this problem when:

1. Using emacs in the terminal
2. In another mode, cpp mode, java mode, etc

I also get the same character sequence printed when I press `C-d` as an alternative to delete.

It may be helpful to know that I am using emacs on a Mac and that I downloaded emacs from [here](http://emacsformacosx.com/).

Comment: Where did you get D Mode from?  Emacs does not include D-Mode by default.

Comment: `C-h c DEL` What is the function that it runs when you are in `d-mode`?

Comment: @JustinWood - "C-d (translated from <kp-delete>) runs the command "$(D "

Comment: @lunaryorn - You'll note that I removed most of the file, so I'm not sure how closely these things are related. That said, the original file comes from here: https://github.com/Emacs-D-Mode-Maintainers/Emacs-D-Mode/blob/master/d-mode.el

Comment: Do you have any `d-mode-hook`s in your `.emacs` file?

Comment: @JustinWood - Darn, yes I do, at the very bottom, grabbed 'em from someone else's .emacs! Found the problem - thanks! Can't believe search didn't find the issue earlier.